# Need to upgrade docker memory in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy an application in EC2 through docker. 
For testing in local I had to increase the docker ram to 4 gb which i did through Docker UI (preference->advance).

now for EC2 instance, Can somebody please suggest how to increase the docker memory from command prompt.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/. Look at the memory params

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer, so posting it here,

In EC2, docker size depends on the size of the instance itself.
if the EC2 has 16Gb ram, then docker container will have same ram.

Comment: reference plz ?

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding, your docker is taking memory more than expected.

You can check using the command `sudo docker stats` and can see the memory allocation for the docker.

As I see for myself it is `3.813GiB` which is very high and apprx  50% of all memory.

[image]

Solution:
It would be best if you allocated less memory, I updated my `docker-compose.yaml` file and added below line to allocate and reserve the memory for docker as:

```
  deploy:
   resources:
    limits:
     memory: 512M
    reservations:
     memory: 300M
```

After adding the above line your docker will take up to 512MB.

[image]

**Here are sample `docker-compose.yaml` file**

```
version: '3' # Use version 3 or higher

services: # Use 'services' (plural) to define your services
 backend:
  container_name: track_easy_server_container
  image: track_easy_server_image
  deploy:
   resources:
    limits:
     memory: 512M
    reservations:
     memory: 300M
  build:
   context: .
   target: production
   dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  command: npm run start:prod
  environment:
   - APP_ENV=PROD
  env_file: .env
  ports:
   - '3010:3010'
  volumes:
   - .:/user/src/app
   - /usr/src/app/node_modules
  restart: unless-stopped
```

This is how I resolved my problem.

Now check the memory if it is still the same then run the command `sudo docker system prune` it will delete the **unused build-cache objects** and free up the memory too.

[image]